# Post function with nodejs and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm new on NodeJS and I'm trying to create an api service, I've created the get function and it's working good but the post function not:

```
router.post("/venditori",function(req,res){
        var query = "INSERT INTO ??(??,??,??,??,??) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        var table = ["venditori","name","surname","company","email","password",req.body.name,req.body.surname,req.body.company,req.body.email,md5(req.body.password)];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "User Added !"});
            }
        });
    });
```

and show me this error:

```
TypeError: Object function (size) {  if ('number' == typeof size) return convert(size);  var parts = size.match(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
*(kb|mb|gb|tb)$/)    , n = parseFloat(parts[1])    , type = parts[2];

 var map = {
     kb: 1 << 10    , mb: 1 << 20    , gb: 1 << 30    , tb: ((1 << 30) * 1024)  };

 return map[type] * n; } has no method 'parse'
      at getRawBody (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:86:21)
      at read (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:64:3)
      at urlencodedParser (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:104:5)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
      at trim_prefix (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
      at /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
      at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
      at next (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
      at expressInit (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:23:5)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(req,res);` just before  `var query = ...` and paste it here. It looks like these two variables are not serialized as JSON, this could happen when `/users` not returning expected values.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed removing the node_modules dir and running a new npm installation with another package.json the query was OK the problem was related with a version of body-parser and jwt-simple

Answer (score 0):

Note that an 'error' from MySQL is an actual error that prevents correct execution, e.g. a syntax error.  An 'error' from an INSERT statement may actually be a successful execution, but a failed operation; e.g. a unique key violation, etc.

In your code, you need to look at 'result.affectedRows' to determine if the query executed correctly but the statement failed.  A value of '0' means the INSERT statement executed correctly but failed to insert a row, for whatever reason.  A value of '1' means success.  Something like this:

```
    connection.query(query,function(err,result) {
        if(err) {
            // this is a SQL execution error
            res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
        } else { // these are execution 'successes' which include failures
            if(result.affectedRows == 1) { // succesful INSERT
                res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "User Added !"});
            } else if(result.affectedRows == 0) { // failed INSERT
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "INSERT failed !"});
            }
        }
    });
```

More on this is here: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#getting-the-number-of-affected-rows